# what parameters to pass to invalidate(left, top,right,bottom) for google map on android?

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, invalidation

what parameters do I pass to this function ?

invalidate(left, top, right, bottom)

for use with google map on android ?

thanks

-
ahsan

Comment: i was trying (0,0,100,100) but not sure if thats ok or not :-s

Answer (score 1):

You pass whatever rectangle you need invalidated. It may be simpler to use the `invalidate()` that takes no parameters.

Comment: i have a big map and lots of overlays, just using invalidate() is not efficient. I was trying to specify the area to invalidate. Please help. thanks. :)

Comment: in other words, what should be the coordinates on the screen and how to know ?

Comment: @Ahsan: If you do not know what needs to be invalidated, do not call `invalidate()` -- what makes you think it needs to be invalidated in the first place?

Comment: well, I h ave a few routes which may or may not be overlaid based on choice. So if they are overlaid or otherwise, I need to call invalidate to remove the previous overlay, right ?

Comment: @Ahsan: Yes, but most likely you will need to call the zero-parameter `invalidate()`, AFAIK. If you can figure out a smaller rectangle based upon the old overlay's route, perhaps you can invalidate a smaller region, but I have no idea how easy or difficult that will be for you.